# How to run a docker image of ElasticSearch with SSPL licence?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch

I am developing a spring-boot application with the aid of the new ElasticSearch Java Client 8.4.
I need an ElasticSearch server running on docker with same version. Otherwise, some queries may not be performed because of incompatibility issues.

I know that ElasticSearh is no more open source from version 7.10, and has 2 kind of licences.

Question is, how may I implement an Elasticseach server on Docker by using free licence? What should I do at code level?

Thanks

Comment: See: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/licenses/ELASTIC-LICENSE-2.0.txt  
which is referred in the official elastic docker image: https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch  
As with all docker images other software is included too which you should check, but at a fast glance it should be fine.

Comment: "open source" and "free" are not the same. just because something isn't open source, doesn't mean it isn't free, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can and download the docker image from their [website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#_pull_the_elasticsearch_docker_image).

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.4.3
```

Refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/pricing/faq/licensing) page to understand more about Elasticsearch license change

Comment: Could you please provide a proof of that so I can show this to my lead architech? Thanks!

Comment: @SaverioMirkoViola just added more links :)